# Negative numerical result when integrating a strictly non-negative integrand

Tags: numerical-integration

Although there are similar posts here [Negative integral of a positive function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65914/negative-integral-of-a-positive-function) ,
[Positive integrand giving negative answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30105/positive-integrand-giving-negative-answer) ,

my case is even more surprising. I have a very simple function

```
Clear[y]
y[q_, w_] := Module[{res},
 res = If[w > q (2 - q), 0, w];
 If[w > Abs[q (2 - q)] && w < q (2 + q), res = 1 - 1/4 (q - w/q)^2];
 If[w < 0, res = 0];
 res
 ]
```

It looks like this

```
g1 = Plot[y[0.25, w], {w, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Numerical and analytical integrals are equal

```
Integrate[y[0.25, w], {w, 0, 4}]
NIntegrate[y[0.25, w], {w, 0, 4}]
(*0.0957031*)
```

Now let us shift the function

```
g2 = Plot[y[0.25, w-2], {w, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and integrate again in the same limits

```
Integrate[y[0.25, w - 2], {w, 0, 4}]
NIntegrate[y[0.25, w - 2], {w, 0, 4}]
(*-1.9043*)
```

The result is now negative and not equal to the previous value! What's up?

In this particular case i am not so much interested in the origin of such peculiar result, but rather in the practical prescription on how to deal with it.

Comment: I think the result `0.0957031` is also wrong. Redefine your function as `Clear[y];y[q_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] :=  ...` and run both `NIntegrate[y[0.25, w], {w, 0, 4}]` and `NIntegrate[y[0.25, w - 2], {w, 0, 4}]`.

Comment: @march I see that I get the same result (0.124349) for the `w` and `w-2` cases by forcing the arguments to be numeric, the question is why does that work?

Comment: I think your function doesn't generally do what you intend. Try `y[a,b]`. It's strange to be using a module for this. Less strange, but more troublesome, is using `If` instead of `Piecewise`.

Comment: Yes, what @JohnDoty said. Certainly `Integrate` is not going to work correctly, because `y` doesn't evaluate correctly symbolically, and `Integrate` manipulates symbolic expressions. `NIntegrate` is also failing probably because it does symbolic pre-processing before it does the numerical integration, and so the function doesn't evaluate correctly as an integrand.

Comment: @march Thank you for your suggestion. I have also explored another route by expressing everything in terms of the "UnitStep" function (this is in line suggestions of @ Jack Lavigne ). So I have solutions in both, numerical and analytical, ways. Should I delete this question as too simple? Can one, actually, learn anything from my question?

Answer (score 4):

There is some confusion using `Plot`. Compare the plot of the non-evaluated `y` in the question with the plot of the evaluated `y`:

```
Grid[{{Plot[y[0.25, w - 2], {w, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   Plot[Evaluate@y[0.25, w - 2], {w, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Medium]}}]
```

[image]

We can see that going through the algorithmic steps of defining the value `y` with symbolic arguments produces an expression that would give different values over the domain of `y` if using numerical arguments.

> In this particular case i am not so much interested in the origin of
>   such peculiar result, but rather in the practical prescription on how
>   to deal with it.

Since in the question both `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` are used let us redefine `y` with `Piecewise`.

```
res1 = Piecewise[{{0, w > q (2 - q)}}, w]
res2 = Piecewise[{{1 - 1/4 (q - w/q)^2, 
    w > Abs[q (2 - q)] && w < q (2 + q)}}, res1]
res3 = Piecewise[{{0, w < 0}}, res2]
```

[image]

With that definition we get positive results for the integrals in the question.

```
Block[{q = 0.25},
 NIntegrate[res3, {w, 0, 4}]
]

(* 0.124349 *)

Integrate[res3, {w, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

### Using IntegrationMonitor

Using the [option `IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/34008) can help in these kind of situations. In this case we clearly see that the integrant is not what it is expected:

[image]

Comment: I'd prolly run `//PiecewiseExpand //Simplify` on `res3` before feeding it to the integration, if I were the OP.

Comment: It is a good idea. I did not post the expanded version of `res3` because that would be harder to evaluate for correctness of its definition.